# DropDownLists becoming TextBoxes - Should the user be able to go back?

Tags: website-design, interaction-design, navigation, dropdown

So I have a menu on web application I am developing. In this menu, there is an option for how many Project vacancies one wishes to create. The user can choose as many as they need (large numbers will prompt a confirmation to ensure the user hasn't made a mistake).

The first way of choosing is a small Drop Down List that looks like this:

[image: Drop Down List, unselected]

When you open said list, you are prevented with these options:

[image: Choices available]

If one decides that 5 is not enough, you can select "More..." and the Drop Down List changes to a text box:

[image: Custom entry for the number of Vacancies]

When I showed this to my tech lead, his first question was "Can you go back to the List?"

I instantly thought that having such an option was inappropriate, as I felt it would clutter up my nice menu, where I like to keep things minimal for things like this.

My question is - **Is this the right choice? Should I give the user the option to go back to the list? Does it matter?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spin control suits your requirement.

[image]

user can increase or decrease the number by clicking on up-arrow or down-arrow. This can be controlled to be between two numbers

Comment: +1 for re-evaluating the situation and providing a nice and simple solution

Comment: Due to a requirements change the Boss doesn't want a "number of roles" option anymore, but this was a good answer, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If someone decides that they now want to select 3 instead of 15, **they can already go back** just by entering 3 instead of 15.  Sure, the interaction is slightly different, but I can't imagine anyone being confused by this.

You should limit the inputs of the text box to numbers (and indicate that clearly), so that you don't get answers like "fifteen".

Personally, I would prefer not having the dropdown in the first place, and only having the text field as I can fill it in faster and it is cleaner.

Comment: +1 for not having a dropdown. Users aren't going to read the dropdown options to help make their decision, and there's no concern for mis-spelling here, so a dropdown is only making the process harder.

Answer (score 3):

User should be (always) allowed to undo his action. This is a good UX practice.

If you want to stick to your design of drop down menu + more, then I'd suggest you add an input box beside the drop down list in case of  more. This makes it quite easy for the user to re-select a lower number.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0n2qQ.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>